# Git repository to a dependency in package.json

Tags: angularjs, git, reactjs, repository, package.json

I am having a git repository and want to use this repository as a dependency in package.json file of some other project so that it can be downloaded as we run npm command.
can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
"dependencies": {
    "<repo>": "<user>/<repo>#<branch>",
}
```

Example:

```
"dependencies": {
   "botkit": "jonchurch/botkit#master",
}
```

[Reference is here!](https://medium.com/@jonchurch/use-github-branch-as-dependency-in-package-json-5eb609c81f1a)

Answer (score 2):

From the [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies):

Git URLs as Dependencies

```
git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
```

Comment: can you please elaborate little more?

Answer (score 0):

Try below format in your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies" : {
  "projectName" : "git://github.com/user/project.git"
}
```

Comment: Could not install /tmp/npm-14485-f3914b67/git-cache-5670ae183f1b/efb22ee81642ce5f041c7e9f0e793c5618f569cf       this error is coming