# How to import a forked npm package of Github in Laravel Mix?

Tags: laravel, github, npm, laravel-mix, git-fork

In `package.json`, I have:

```
"vue-search-select": "github:my-github-account/vue-search-select"
```

And then run `npm install`, no error.

In `app.js`, I try to import the forked package:

```
import { ModelSelect } from 'vue-search-select';
```

When I run `npm run watch`, got the below message:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-search-select'
```

**UPDATE:**

I compared the original version and forked version in `node_modules`: Original contains `dist` folder but forked version don't have. In github, the original one also don't have this folder. And `dist` is included in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that, for [`package.json` GitHub URL](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#github-urls), As of version 1.1.65, you can refer to GitHub URLs as just `foo:user/foo-project`, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45421710/6309).

But I would still recommend a [more complete URL instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36078490/6309):

```sh
git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
```

That way, you control the scheme (HTTPS or SSH) and can check which credentials (cached username/password for HTTPS or private key for SSH) is used.

The [OP Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7573253/wilson) comments in [the discussion](https://%5B) that adding `dist/` to the repo could be an option, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40528869/6309).
A [`prepare` script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57829251/6309) can be declared in the package.json, such as [this one](https://github.com/cinderblock/node-MLX90363/blob/09d44d8abc94f728f1c5ea93c22fe9b4f87d9076/package.json#L14-L17).

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
```

As noted in Wilson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71573308/6309)

> the important thing is that the `prepare` script is **added in forked package**, *not* in the project that using the package.

Comment: Thanks. But I ran `npm install` with no errors. And I can check the code in `node_modules/vue-multiselect` is match with the forked version. Seems `foo:user/foo-project` work fine?

Comment: @Wilson Strange, if the installation works, something else must trigger the `Module not found` error

Comment: I compared the original version and forked version in `node_modules`:
Original contains `dist` folder but forked version don't have.
In github, the original one also don't have this folder. And `dist` is included in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Should I remove `dist` in `.gitignore`?

Comment: @Wilson dist is usually ignored (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/ce5da10a3a43c4dd8bd9572eda17c0a37ee0eac1/Node.gitignore#L92), so you should leave it ignored.

Comment: But I don't know how to solve this issue.I think the reason is that the `dist` folder is only in npm but not in github.

Comment: @Wilson dist content is supposed to be regenerated, which is why it is not versioned (plus, a Git repository is not a good fit for large binaries)

Comment: But it doesn't regenerated when I run `npm run watch` / `npm install`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243177/discussion-between-vonc-and-wilson).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution:

Add `"prepare": "npm run lib:build"` (or something else depends on the package how to build, can check it in `package.json`)  to `scripts` of `package.json` to the forked package. And push to github.

Then, in the project that using the forked package, just keep `"package-name": "github:my-github-account/package-name"` in `package.json` and run `npm install` again. No other changes.

Comment: Yes, I did mention the prepare script in my own edited answer

Comment: @VonC Thanks, I think the important thing is that the `prepare` script is add in  forked package not in the project that using the package. I got it wrong at first.